# Plugin is too old

Tags: android, gradle

I know this question isn't new, but I really couldn't find the solution for me.

Im getting the

> Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set
>   ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
>   "3915652b2897b86e86ec1d347be9193f1139098e"

error while trying to build the project.
build.gradle classpath:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'
```

wrapper:

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

now when I`m using lower version of gradle it builds the project but the instant run isn't working because it requires the alpha2.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of gradle plugin is `2.2.0-alpha4`

You can find the name of latest version in the [Bintray repository](https://jfrog.com/distribution/?bintrayRD=1) or on the badge in the bottom of the answer :)

[ ![Download] [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200827200154/https://api.bintray.com/packages/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/images/download.svg)][3](https://jfrog.com/distribution/?bintrayRD=1)